# DB2 generate DLL error

Tags: dll, db2

Earlier this morning I trying to create DLL for my DB2 database but it kept giving the following message:

The DB2 Administration Server encountered a script error.  Script 
error code "1".

Explanation:

A script error was encountered while the DB2 Administration server was
executing the script. The script exited with error code "".

User response:

Verify that the script is correct.

If you continue to receive this error message after attempting the
suggested response, refer to the DB2 Administration Server's First
Failure Data Capture Log for additional information or contact IBM
Support.

can anyone help me on this?
my user is ROOT and schema is SQLJ 
command is  db2look -d OBDB -z SQLJ -u ROOT -e  -l  -x  -c ;
Error code is SQL22220.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i once too had this problem. may be you are trying to generate dll for more than 30 tables at a time. reduce the no. of tables and see if this works. worked for me though but errors can be due to other reason as well, plz let me know.... :)

Comment: sure the error can be due to table restriction, but i checked it, I had no such issues. can you give me another solution?

Comment: sorry for now, but i will tell you if I get solution

Comment: we both share the same name :D I think its funny :) one vishal helping another vishal